# how to redirect any webpage to another in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have laravel project and I have the following htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?thebooks.ca$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /book_donation/public/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?thebooks.ca$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ book_donation/public/ [L]
```

but it seems it only work when I request thebooks.ca not any other url like thebooks.ca/foo so how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You write this code in index.php

?
header("location: http://thebooks.ca/foo/");
?>